# Converting Flex Application to A View

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I am attempting to convert the scheduling sample 1 of Flexlib into a view.

https://github.com/flex-users/flexlib

When I placed it in a view, I was having an issue with this line:

```
<flexlib:ScheduleViewer id="scheduleViewer"  
            width="600" height="400" 
            dataProvider="{dataProvider }"       
            startDate="{startDate}" endDate="{endDate}" />
```

I noticed that when I had this line:

```
xmlns:flexlib="http://code.google.com/p/flexlib/"
```

I got this error:

```
Could not resolve <flexlib:ScheduleViewer> to a component implementation.
```

When I changed that line to this:

```
xmlns:flexlib="libs.flexlib.scheduling.*"
```

I get this error:

```
1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: ScheduleViewer.
```

Additionally, I have placed the flexlib.swc into my libs folder. Here is the code as a whole:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"  
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:flexlib="libs.flexlib.scheduling.*"
    creationComplete="onCreationComplete();">

<fx:Style>
    .myEntryStyle {
        fillAlphas: 1, 1;
        fillColors: #ff0000, #990000;
        timeStyleName: "myTimeStyle";
        color: #000000;
    }
    .myTimeStyle {
        fontSize: 9;
        fontWeight: bold;
        color: #ffff00;
    }
</fx:Style>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import flexlib.scheduling.scheduleClasses.SimpleScheduleEntry;
        import flexlib.scheduling.util.DateUtil;
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        [Bindable]         
        private var dataProvider : ArrayCollection;         
        [Bindable]
        private var startDate : Date;
        [Bindable]
        private var endDate : Date;

        private function onCreationComplete() : void
        {
            setTimeframe();
            initDataProvider();
        }

        private function setTimeframe() : void
        {
            startDate = DateUtil.clearTime( new Date() );
            endDate = getEndDate( startDate );
        }

        private function getEndDate( startDate : Date ) : Date
        {
            var duration : Number = DateUtil.DAY_IN_MILLISECONDS * 1;
            var endDate : Date = new Date( startDate.getTime() + duration );
            return endDate;
        }

        private function initDataProvider() : void
        {
            var entries : ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            var entry : SimpleScheduleEntry = new SimpleScheduleEntry();
            entry.startDate = DateUtil.clearTime( new Date() );
            entry.endDate = new Date( entry.startDate.getTime() + DateUtil.HOUR_IN_MILLISECONDS * 5 );
            entry.label = "Our first entry!";
            entries.addItem( entry );

            entry = new SimpleScheduleEntry();
            entry.startDate = DateUtil.setTime( new Date(), DateUtil.HOUR_IN_MILLISECONDS );
            entry.endDate = new Date( entry.startDate.getTime() + DateUtil.HOUR_IN_MILLISECONDS * 15 );
            entry.label = "Our second entry!";
            entries.addItem( entry );

            entry = new SimpleScheduleEntry();
            entry.startDate = DateUtil.setTime( new Date(), DateUtil.HOUR_IN_MILLISECONDS * 13 );
            entry.endDate = new Date( entry.startDate.getTime() + DateUtil.HOUR_IN_MILLISECONDS * 5 );
            entry.label = "Our third entry!";
            entries.addItem( entry );

            dataProvider = entries;
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<flexlib:ScheduleViewer id="scheduleViewer"  
                        width="600" height="400" 
                        dataProvider="{ dataProvider }"       
                        startDate="{ startDate }" endDate="{ endDate }" />
    </s:View>
```

Does anybody know what my issue with converting this sample to a view is?

Comment: IT sounds like the compiler isn't finding the FlexLib swc.  Even though you say you've put it in the libs path, you may want to get the code and recompile it for the version of the SDK you're using.  ( I presume Flex 4.6 ).  I'll also add that most of Flexlib is from the days before Spark and long before the days of mobile development.  I would not expect the FlexLib components to work well.  They may also have dependencies to the MX libraries [which are not available from the mobile projects]; but I don't know for sure.

Comment: I got it working, though it was extremely unorthodox. I created a new mobile project and replaced everything (I noticed there were some lingering library references I wasn't using). I couldn't get it to reference the swc, but I accessed it using the expanded library. I also had to delete some files from that library that were causing errors even though I wasn't using them in the project. I will play around with it a bit more still.